# remove outer double quotes from array of strings

Tags: javascript

If `x = "[1, 2, 3]"` then doing `JSON.parse("[1, 2, 3]")` returns `[1, 2, 3]`. If `x = "['a', 'b', 'c']"`
how can I remove the outer double quotes please?

Comment: use valid JSON? Only way around it is evil eval or new Function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real solution is fix whatever is producing invalid JSON and make it valid.

If you can not fix it, you can manipulate the data as long as you can say that the content will not have any quotes, a simple replace can fix it.

```js
var x = "['a', 'b', 'c']";
var obj = JSON.parse(x.replace(/'/g,'"'));
console.log(obj);
```

If the content might have quotes, you can try to escape them out.

Other unsafe option is using new Function

```js
var x = "['a', 'b', 'c']";
var obj = (new Function('return ' + x))();
console.log(obj);
```

And it can be done with eval also.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the use of single quote which makes it not a valid Json.
reminder: JSON.parse parse valid json where a string is surounded by double quotes only (different from javascript object where you can use interchangeably "" '' ``)

```
JSON.parse(x.replace(/'/g,'"'))
```